# NSTableView reloading a group cell without using reloadData?

Tags: nstableview

Is there any way to make a view based NStableView reload its group cells from its datasource/delegate?

- reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes: - although the documentation doesn't mention it, it only works for non group cells
- reloadData - works fine but I would like to avoid it since it's a bit overkill for what I'm trying to do.

I have other solutions for this problem (such as using binding for the textFields I want to have changed, or "manually" getting the cell from the table view and changing its textfield values).

But it seems silly that there's no way to reload a group cell..

Am I missing something or should I file a radar with this?